# Dynamic SQL, how to code ' ' to dynamic SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

Good Morning

```
select CASE t.gift_club_start_date
       WHEN ' '  THEN ' '
       ELSE SUBSTR(t.gift_club_start_date,5,2)|| '/' ||SUBSTR(t.gift_club_start_date,7,2)|| '/' ||SUBSTR(t.gift_club_start_date,1,4) 
       END
from GIFT t
```

This shows if rows is empty, it shows empty.

I try to do this code with Dynamic SQL

```
'select CASE t.gift_club_start_date
       WHEN '' ''  THEN '' ''
       ELSE SUBSTR(t.gift_club_start_date,5,2)|| ''/'' ||SUBSTR(t.gift_club_start_date,7,2)|| ''/'' ||SUBSTR(t.gift_club_start_date,1,4) 
       END
from GIFT t'
```

BUT output shows this // ,when row is empty.

So how can I code correctly to show empty row?   This line `WHEN '' ''  THEN '' ''`

Thank you so mcuh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can use double `'` to solve:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vSQL varchar2(100);
  3      vVar varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5      vSQL := 'select '' '' from dual';
  6      execute immediate vSQL into vVar;
  7      dbms_output.put_line('result:<' || vVar || '>');
  8  end;
  9  /
result:< >
```

Another way could be the following:

```
SQL> declare
  2      vSQL varchar2(100);
  3      vVar varchar2(100);
  4  begin
  5      vSQL := q'[select ' ' from dual]';
  6      execute immediate vSQL into vVar;
  7      dbms_output.put_line('result:<' || vVar || '>');
  8  end;
  9  /
result:< >
```

For your situation, notice that "empty" is different from `' '`; if you need to check for null values, you should use something like

```
WHEN t.gift_club_start_date is NULL THEN...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `||CHR(39)`

```
'WHEN ' || CHR(39) || CHR(39) || ' THEN ' || CHR(39) || ' ' ||CHR(39)
```